# How to formulate a mapping function in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I wanted to prove two sets are equal. For that I assume that there is a mapping function that maps from domain set to range set. Let the range set be one among the two sets which are equal. Also consider the universal set as domain set. So if we have same function and same domain in two cases,will the resultant range set also be equal? Also how do I formulate such a mapping function?

Answer (score 1):

The easier and MOSTLY used method to show 2 sets are equal is to prove that $x\in A$ iff $x\in B$.

Now why exactly is your method of proving that 2 sets are equal generally harder?

Well let me phrase it in a concise way

2 sets $A$ and $B$ are equal iff

There exists a bijection(denoted by $f$) such that $f = I$. Where $I$ is the identity map (or equivalently $f(x) = x$)

This is more difficult to prove since you have to either construct a bijection which is also the identity, or prove it exists. Now proving there exists a bijection is hard enough, and for 2 general sets is VERY difficult since we would need to know how to compute $f$ and on top of that proving that out of the set of functions which is a bijection the identity (i.e $f$ s.t $f(x) = x$) also belongs to that set.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What is understood is that " if the mapping function mentioned is a bijective function (one-to-one), the resultant range sets will be equal given the domain set is same". In that case,  is there a need to prove it in the other way using subset concept of "x belongs to the set A iff x belongs to the set B" ?

Comment: No a bijective function(or mapping) is a function which is injective(one to one, i.e If f(x) = f(y) then x = y) AND surjective(onto, i.e every element(Let's denote A element y) in the Co- domain has an element in the domain(Let's denote it x)  s.t f(x) = y, and another way to formulate it is the condition im f(the range) = Co-domain. And the standard way to formulate it is to prove for 2 sets that "x belongs to the set A iff x belongs to the set B".

Comment: And you can also prove that those 2 different ways of proof our equivalent(The other way is to prove there exists a bijection function between 2 sets s.t it is the identity)